# SendKeys wreaks havoc on number lock

Tags: ms-access, vba

In a continuous form, I am trying to copy the field value from the previous record when I Got Focus of the field by sending SendKeys. 
Every time the field get focus, my number lock toggles.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
Private Sub SampleDate_GotFocus()
 SendKeys "^'", True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old bug. As a workaround you can use function below instead on SendKeys, but best solution - avoid SendKeys at all if it's possible.

```
Sub mySendKeys(sKeys As String, Optional bWait As Boolean = False)
Dim bNumLockState As Boolean
Dim bCapsLockState As Boolean
Dim bScrollLockState As Boolean
    bNumLockState = IsNumLockOn()
    bCapsLockState = IsCapsLockOn()
    bScrollLockState = IsScrollLockOn()
    SendKeys sKeys, bWait
    If IsNumLockOn() <> bNumLockState Then
        ToggleNumLock
    End If
    If IsCapsLockOn() <> bCapsLockState Then
        ToggleCapsLock
    End If
    If IsScrollLockOn() <> bScrollLockState Then
        ToggleScrollLock
    End If
End Sub
```